# How can I fix keys on my Dell laptop that have become harder to press?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, dell-inspiron, laptop-repair

A couple of days ago, my son spilled soda on one side of my laptop computer. Upon using it, I discovered that some of the keys in that area have become difficult to press down, they work just fine but I have to apply extra pressure and this especially affects the flow of my typing as I type quite fast, except for when I have to use those difficult keys... I'm scared of taking off these keys to clean the residue as Ill probably break them in the process. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are worried about breaking the keys take it to a repair shop.

Comment: I'm in an area where such shops aren't easily accessible.... That will be my last resort if all else fails

Answer (score 0):

I add **small scratch of folded paper** under those keys, that works.
Acer A0751h, those keyboards keys could be lifted up one by one.