# Is it possible to remove keys from Dell Inspiron 11-3513 laptop keyboard by myself without damaging anything?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, dell-inspiron, typing

I spilled juice on my laptop and i will like to know if and how i can take off the keys and clean whatever residue and put them back myself as it will be hard for me to get it done professionally.

Comment: Possible, yes. Easy, no. & just getting the keys off isn't enough, you need to get to the actual contacts & PCB underneath & also check the limit of the ingress. Get it to a professional.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix keys on my Dell laptop that have become harder to press?](http://superuser.com/questions/1074151/how-can-i-fix-keys-on-my-dell-laptop-that-have-become-harder-to-press)

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers). If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try this:
remove the kbd
place into dishwasher and run thru a cycle with just water
Dry in oven on lowest setting for a day
leave in open air for another day.
replace.

THE KEY IS LETTING IT DRY THOROUGHLY BEFORE REUSE.

Don't laugh, this is done for every piece of equipment that comes into major repair facilities.